# Who can verify my implementation of react menu?

Tags: reactjs

I’m studying REACT on official documentation and on the course at Udemy. I want to create an online store, first I made a small template for the site menu. Who can check the code and give feedback so that I could make the menu and the online store better? Thanks.

https://github.com/Quintis1212/react-app-prod - production

https://quintis1212.github.io/react-build/build/index.html - build

Comment: This sounds like a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com, though definitely check their help section regarding off-site links vs. posting code.